# VLC quit with execution command

Tags: php, vlc

i use an execution command from VLC plugin to record a live stream from my server and it work fine. but also i need to get a message that the record is finished. i have tried this command but when the record is more than 30 sec, a error appear.

this is the command :

```
$file = 'vlc '.$inputstream.' --run-time='.$sec.' --sout "#duplicate{dst=display{noaudio},dst=std{access=file,mux=mov,dst='.$path.'}" vlc://quit ';
echo exec($file);
```

and this is the error :

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\wamp\www\IPTVStream\target_2.php on line 14

kindly, can you help me how i can use VLC quit with execution command ?

regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `set_time_limit(0);` before calling the `exec` function. This removes the time limit

Comment: Dear anurupr, when i use set_time_limit(0); this does not affect the behaviour of php or apache server ? because sometimes i need to record for few hours.

Comment: it will not affect the behaviour of `php` or `apache server` but the script will be running till the `vlc` command has completed

Comment: are you doing anything else in this php script or does it simply call the `vlc` command?

Comment: then it should not affect the behaviour of php or apache.